# Comparing the pattern of commensal of two drugs over time

Tags: time-series, group-differences, medicine

I would naturally appreciate your advice on the following problem:

Following operations, patients can be started either Drug A or Drug B to prevent blood clots forming in patients calves. We surveyed $36$ doctors on which day they start either of these medications after surgery. There is wide variation when either drug is started. Some physicians start the medication after $1$ day and others after $14$ days. Which test could I use to check to see whether the distributions of when the Drug A and Drug B started are the same or statistically different?